# Sending a json document using a supplied certificate

Tags: json, vb.net, ssl

I have been supplied a certificate that is required to send a json claim to an uri that has an api for sending the claim.  The line in error is: handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate)

The following is my code:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
 Dim path As String = "E:\DRDRW_Update\Web Based Billing\vendorsupplied.pfx"
 Dim password As String = "Password"
 Dim strGateway As String = "https://MCE/api/WebServiceClaim"
 Dim collection = New X509Certificate2Collection()
 collection.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
 Dim certificate = collection(0)

 Dim PathClaim As String = "E:\Sample Claim Submission JSON.txt"
 Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(PathClaim)
 Dim jsonclaim As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName)

 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
 Dim handler As New WebRequestHandler()

 handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate)
 ' custom certificate validation handler to ignore untrusted remote certificate
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate)
 Using client = New HttpClient(handler)
       Dim serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonclaim)
       Dim content = New StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            content.Headers.Add("header1", "header2") ' require header
            content.Headers.Add("token", "xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz")
       Dim result = client.PostAsync(strGateway, content).Result ' ensures task is synchronous
       ' deserialize the saveresultmodel from the WS response and check for claim validation errors
       Dim success As Boolean = False
       If result.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
           Dim resultResult As String = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
           Dim claimResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultResult)
           If claimResult.Errors.Count = 0 Then
               success = True
           Else
               ' output error results to console
               For Each [error] In claimResult.Errors
                   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject([error]))
               Next [error]
           End If
       End If
 End Using
End Sub

Public Class WebRequestHandler
   Inherits HttpClientHandler
End Class
```

Comment: I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is the error?  Please edit your question to include the exact error message.  Next - I am confused why you have a new class for the WebRequestHandler.  I think you mean for the handler to be a `System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler`  Delete your new `WebRequestHandler` class and change `Dim handler` to `As New System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler`.

Comment: When I changed the line to: Dim handler As New System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler

Comment: When I changed the line to:                                                                       Dim handler As New System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler the project will not compile .  Says that System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler is not defined?  I have Imports System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler included? @GMan80013

Comment: The original code with Dim handler As New WebRequestHandler() the line where I try and add the certificate     handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate) the error says that ClientCertificatesis not part of RetrieveData.WebRequestHandler?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have declared your own class for the WebRequestHandler.  This is not the same as the System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler.

Visual Studio had a "nice" feature offering to do this for you when it discovers a missing reference with something like "Generate Class for WebRequestHandler."  This usually happens when you copy/paste code from another source and the reference was not fully defined.  I *never* take this option and find it a weird way to approach writing code.

You do need to change your code to reference the correct handler like so.

```
Dim handler As New System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler
```

The reason you are getting an error with that is that your project now needs a reference to another assembly (dll) with that class in it.  To figure this out, I used google to find the [documentation page here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler(v=vs.110).aspx) and noted this text: Assembly:

> System.Net.Http.WebRequest (in System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll).

This tells us to add the System.Net.Http.WebRequest reference to the project in order to access this class.

Comment: I added the reference to System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll and all worked well.  The next issue I am facing with this code is the line:                        
    Dim result = client.PostAsync(strGateway, content).Result                                            Which gives me the following:An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and I do not know how to correct? @GMan80013

Answer (score 0):

I had two issues, the first was answered by @GMan80013 by putting a reference to System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll.  The other was caused by the use of self-signing certificates.  The  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback function needs to return true to ignore the issue of certificate validation caused by self-signed certificates.